# How can I output a specific images in Deep Learning & Computer Vision

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I have the following lines of code for vehicle recognition:

```
import glob
import imageio
import keras
import tensorflow
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection

detector = ObjectDetection()

model_path = 'C:/Users/yolo/models/yolo.h5'
input_path = 'C:/Users/yolo/input'
output_path = 'C:/Users/yolo/output'

detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath(model_path)
detector.loadModel()
detection = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image = input_path, input_type = "stream", output_image_path = output_path)
```

In `model_path` I have yolov3 model, in `input_path` I have some jpg images with cars, people, bikes, etc... and `output_path` is an empty folder I want to fill it with the car extracted image that has the best accuracy in every image from `input_path`. How can I do that? I think that the last line is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

name output image an output_path=os.path.join(output_path , name+".jpg")

[refer](https://predictivehacks.com/object-detection-with-yolo/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# This line will make other objects unconsierable
custom_objects = detector.CustomObjects(car=True)
# Here you will pass your image and  
detections = detector.detectCustomObjectsFromImage(custom_objects=custom_objects, input_image=imagpe_path, output_image_path=output_image_path, minimum_percentage_probability=min_prob_you_want)
```